# What is the difference between 'irgendwann' and 'manchmal'

Tags: difference, synonym

I cannot understand the difference in the meaning of these two words: `irgendwann` and `manchmal`

As I understand, both are a lesser than `immer`, and more than `nie`. In between.

In my online courses, they are translated respectively `sometime` and `sometimes`...

And as I don't really make a difference in english also... I just wonder if there is really a difference enough in using one or the other.

Could I consider them synonyms ?

Comment: Note that it actually *is* the same thing in English: Sometimes = every now and then, sometime = at some future point of time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, in German they are quite different. Let me explain it with an example:

> Wenn ich traurig bin, trinke ich manchmal Alkohol.
>
> Sometimes, when I’m sad, I drink alcohol.

Another one:

> Irgendwann werde ich das Fahrrad reparieren.
>
> One day I’ll repair the bicycle.

I would translate „irgendwann“ with “eventually”, “one day” or “someday” as it means that something will/might happen in the future (OR has happened in the past; I’m not sure whether this meaning isn’t just colloquial, though). Another example:

> Irgendwann stirbt jeder (Mensch).
>
> Eventually, everybody is going to die.

But beware: “eventually” can also mean „letztlich“/„letztendlich“.

[The Duden explains](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/irgendwann) it quite well using „zu irgendeinem Zeitpunkt“ as an explanation.

EDIT:

I just saw in your profile that you are from Paris so I assume you speak French? I checked a dictionary German->French:

> irgendwann --> « un jour ou l'autre »
>
> manchmal --> « des fois », « parfois », « quelquefois », « à l'occasion », « par moments»

While my French doesn’t go much further than knowing what `Je cherche une chambre` means, it might be helpful for you. Unfortunately, I cannot provide you with the information of which translation of „manchmal“ is the right one.

Conclusion:

„irgendwann“ means “at an uncertain point in time/some time”

„manchmal“ means “sometimes”

Comment: i think i begin to sense the difference: irgendwann, one possibility in the time. Manchmal, several possibilities in the time.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I added some additional pieces of information. Especially the Duden link should help you.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes it helps to look at the question a word can answer.

**Irgendwann** answers to **when?**. It is the most vague answer possible and the temporal equivalent to **irgendwo**.

**Manchmal** answers to **how often?** 
One might say that it is an answer to **when?** but that is a misconception. Examples:

> When do you drink a beer.
>
> Sometimes.

This would pass as a successful communication but only so because the question itself is rather vague and ambiguously phrased. A computer would answer with a list of points in time. **Manchmal** is just a replacement for a rather short list.
So... the context helps out here.
Now, let's try a "real" when-question.

> When did you buy this book?
>
> Manchmal. (sometimes, occasionally)

This doesn't work. But this does:

> Irgendwann. (at some point)

So... **manchmal** is a measure of quantity and is to be seen as the little brother of **often**. 
**Irgendwann** is an indication of a point in time and serves the same function as things like **today**, **later** or **last Wednesday.**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arose from learning by translation. Don't do that! Apparently it helps learn a language but idoes not. Better try to learn by collecting examples.

Or at least find exact translations.

irgendwann = sometime

Sometime next year. Irgendwann nächstes Jahr.
Sometime this week. Irgendwann diese Woche.

manchmal = sometimes = not always

Sometimes I buy Coke and sometimes Pepsi. Manchmal kaufe ich Cola und manchmal Pepsi.

Manchmal gibt er gute Beispiele (und manchmal schlechte).

Comment: He literally mentioned the exact translations in the OP but didn't know the difference in English. This is not really helpful and I strongly disagree about learning a language  by translation.

Comment: @infinitezero I think I understand Eugen Mezei's answer differently than you. I don't see him advising me to learn by translation, but rather to learn by collecting examples.

Comment: I disagree with that point.